# Merging PDF files using Python PyPDF2 and naming new file

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to merge couple of pdf's and put one of those pdf's name for a new file.

```
   import os
   from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
   import datetime
   pdfs = os.listdir(r'C:\Desktop\Work')
   today = datetime.date.today()
   # os.listdir will create the list of all files in a directory
   merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)

   # merger is used for merging multiple files into one and merger.append(absfile) will append 
   the files one by one until all pdfs are appended in the result file.

   for file in pdfs:
   if file.endswith(".pdf"):
    path_with_file = os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Work', file)
    print(path_with_file)
    merger.append(path_with_file,  import_bookmarks=False )
    merger.write(path_with_file)


   merger.close()
```

But I got an

```
error invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'' for merger.write line
```

How can I make that this new file will have same name as old one's which was merged?

Comment: if you make a new file so you can just have a new name, if you want to old name then you can replace the old file with a new file.

Comment: read file paths as command line arguments, don't hard code them, 1 space indentation is a bad choice

Comment: I think your problem is not caused by the name of the file but the PDFs you are using. Could you specify the `pypdf2` version you are using and the full backtrace? Thanks.

Comment: When I'm putting like this `merger.write(r"C:\Desktop\Work\result.pdf")`  It's working, but I want that file name take name from files that I merged, because every time I run code it should get different file name related to files I'm merging.

Comment: What a strange behaviour then. Has the file name any strange character in it? Or maybe the error message has nothing to do with it and the problem is that the program itself has the file open and cannot overwrite it at the same time.

By the way, shouldn't you do the `merger.write` only once? Once all the files have been appended.

Comment: On `PyPDF2` repo you can find some issues related to yours (but not exactly yours from what I have seen). I paste some here: [#133](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/133), [#1034](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/1034), [#925](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/925), [#540](https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/540). Maybe you find a workaround for your case there, but take a look to @GodBlessComputers answer, I think having a named composed of the files you have merged would be the best approach to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is an error of how you copied the code but the second line should be commented as well:

```
   # merger is used for merging multiple files into one and merger.append(absfile) will append 
   the files one by one until all pdfs are appended in the result file.
```

As for the error you're receiving I believe you have to open the file first, making sure it has permission to be read as well.

For having a final filename that is composed of every file you merged you can try concatenating a string.

I tried this and it worked, let me know if it solved the problem:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfMerger
import datetime
pdfs = os.listdir(r'C:\Desktop\Work')
today = datetime.date.today()
# os.listdir will create the list of all files in a directory
merger = PdfMerger(strict=False)

# merger is used for merging multiple files into one and merger.append(absfile) will append 
# the files one by one until all pdfs are appended in the result file.
final_filename = ''

for file in pdfs:
  # Open files
  if file.endswith(".pdf"):
    final_filename += file.split('.')[-2]
    path_with_file = os.path.join(r'C:\Desktop\Work', file)
    input = open(path_with_file, 'rb')
    print(path_with_file)
    print(input.seek(0, os.SEEK_END))
    merger.append(input, import_bookmarks=False)

print(final_filename)

merger.write(f'{final_filename}.pdf')
merger.close()
```

Comment: Name outcome is good, but it didn't create new file

Comment: Put like that `merger.write(os.path.join('C:\\Desktop\\Work', f'{final_filename}.pdf'))`
And it worked, thanks for your help!

Comment: merger.append(input, import_outline=False)